# MySQL: insert current date plus specific time

Tags: mysql, insert

How do I insert a field with current date *and* specific time? 
My goal is to insert CURDATE() with a specific hour 17:30:00.

I tried like 
 `INSERT INTO table VALUES('', CURDATE(+ ' 17:30:00'))` 
 but it doesn't work.

Comment: You want to add some hours to the current date. Right?

Comment: specific hour is not a current date

Comment: try
`INSERT INTO table VALUES('', CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 17:30:00'))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this -

```
  CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 17:30:00')
```

Comment: @Manishearth Read the question. Whats there to explain.

Comment: If the question is such, it's a bad one. _Don't answer, downvote it_ . Code-only answers are bad.

Comment: Well I am not here to decide whats a bad question or a good one. You do it.

Comment: Nothing can be added (except verbosity) to a complete and correct answer. If the question calls for it, code only is fine.

Comment: @JHS I'm giving this a +1 because it's a sufficient and good answer. Some people just want to criticize smarter people.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '17:30:00' HOUR_SECOND))
```

Comment: `INTERVAR` should be `INTERVAL`??

Comment: I got #1064 error. @rabudde's upthere has already answered the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using interval:

```
select interval 17 hour + curdate();
```

Or:

```
select interval '17:30' hour_minute + curdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format your `INSERT`-statement like this to concatenate a date with the time value of your desire:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (yourdatefield)
VALUES (
    CONCAT(CURDATE(), 
    " 01:23:45")
);
```

This statement has of course to be adjusted according to your table and field names and configuration.